# Kerberos AD Spnego authentication fails on one machine but not on another

Tags: java, docker, kerberos, spnego, spring-security-kerberos

I've got a problem with Kerberos authentication. I have a dockerised REST webapp which runs nicely on one AWS host.

I have just tried running it on a new host and I get `java.security.GeneralSecurityException: Checksum failed at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.dk.ArcFourCrypto.decrypt` when I try to call it. Full stacktrace below.

It uses `Spnego` and `Spring Security`.

I don't use keytabs, I rely entirely on the `krb5.conf` configuration like this:

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = XYZ1.AD.XYZ.COM

[realms]
    XYZ1.AD.XYZ.COM  = {
            kdc = XYZ1XEUDC018.xyz1.ad.xyz.com
            default_domain = XYZ1.AD.XYZ.COM
    }

[domain_realm]
    .xyz1.ad.xyz.com = XYZ1.AD.XYZ.COM
    .cd2.xyz.com = XYZ1.AD.XYZ.COM
    .ad.xyz.com = XYZ1.AD.XYZ.COM
```

and this is the Krb5LoginModule `login.conf`:

```
spnego-client {
        com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required;
};

spnego-server {
        com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
        storeKey=true
        isInitiator=false;
};
```

I have found a couple of leads on SO like

[Kerberos/Spnego authentication issue after password change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20247702/kerberos-spnego-authentication-issue-after-password-change)

and

[java security exception : checksum failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911563/java-security-exception-checksum-failed)

but neither shed any light on this problem.

Is there anything I can do with kerberos command line tools to check for issues or differences between the 2 hosts?

The stacktrace:

```
 java.security.GeneralSecurityException: Checksum failed
         at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.dk.ArcFourCrypto.decrypt(ArcFourCrypto.java:408) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
         at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmac.decrypt(ArcFourHmac.java:91) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
         at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType.decrypt(ArcFourHmacEType.java:100) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
         at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType.decrypt(ArcFourHmacEType.java:94) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
         at sun.security.krb5.EncryptedData.decrypt(EncryptedData.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
         at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.authenticate(KrbApReq.java:281) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
         at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.<init>(KrbApReq.java:149) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
         at sun.security.jgss.krb5.InitSecContextToken.<init>(InitSecContextToken.java:108) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
         at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:829) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
         at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:342) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
         at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
         at sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.GSS_acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:906) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
         at sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:556) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
         at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:342) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
         at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
         at net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoAuthenticator.doSpnegoAuth(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:487) ~[spnego-r9.jar!/:na]
         at net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoAuthenticator.authenticate(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:327) ~[spnego-r9.jar!/:na]
         at com.my.app.security.SpnegoAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(SpnegoAuthenticationFilter.java:86) ~[gem-security-1.0.4.jar!/:na]
         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
         at com.my.app.util.servlet.DurationLoggingFilter.doFilter(DurationLoggingFilter.java:36) ~[gem-utilities-1.0.6.jar!/:na]
         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar!/:8.5.15]
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was totally led astray by the security exception and stack trace, looking for external problems when actually the issue was the basic Kerberos/AD configuration.

The service account I am using is not set up for the new host.

You can do this `setspn /Q HTTP/mynewhost.ddd.xyz.com` to see which accounts are set up.

Also [creating an spn from a linux build server](https://serverfault.com/questions/770744/creating-an-spn-from-a-linux-build-server)

Comment: You should self-accept this answer.  This will help better signpost the question to people searching about this question via Google searches.